# How to get a pageToken for the files.list API endpoint of the Google Drives API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drives API for the first time and I cannot find anywhere how to use the API's `pageToken` system. Below is a snippet of example code taking directly from googles web editor.

```js
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for drive.files.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      "includeItemsFromAllDrives": true,
      "orderBy": "name",
      "pageSize": 1000,
      "q": "'FOLDER_ID' in parents",
      "supportsAllDrives": true,
      "fields": "files(name,fileExtension,starred,size)"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Currently, the code above, only returns 1000 files. According to the documentation it should also include a `nextPageToken`, but the example code does not return that token.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list using the method of "Files: list " in Drive API v3 with googleapis for Javascript.

  - In this case, you want to use `pageToken`.
- You have already been able to get values from Google Drive using Drive API.

In this case, how about the following modification? When you use the property of `fields`, in order to return the value of `nextPageToken`, it is required to include `nextPageToken` in the value of `fields`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function getList(pageToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      "includeItemsFromAllDrives": true,
      "orderBy": "name",
      "pageSize": 1000,
      "q": "'FOLDER_ID' in parents",
      "supportsAllDrives": true,
      "fields": "files(name,fileExtension,starred,size),nextPageToken",
      "pageToken": pageToken
    }).then(res => resolve(res)).catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

async function execute() {
  let fileList = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const obj = await getList(pageToken).catch(err => console.log(err));
    if (obj.result.files.length > 0) fileList = [...fileList, ...obj.result.files];
    pageToken = obj.result.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  console.log(fileList)
}
```

- When this script is run, the file list over 1000 files is retrieved using `nextPageToken`.

#### Note:

- If you want to use the method of "Files: list" with Google Apps Script, the following threads might be useful. In this case, Drive API of Advanced Google services of Google Apps Script is version 2. Please be careful this.

  - [How to make this google script more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67649947/7108653)
  - [Is there anyway to use 'size' as a search parameter with DriveApp.searchFiles in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64346280/7108653)
  - [Google sheet script timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51113444/7108653)
  - The sample script of Google Apps Script using your parameters is as follows. When you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

    ```
      function myFunction() {
        let fileList = [];
        let pageToken = "";
        do {
          const obj = Drive.Files.list({
            "includeItemsFromAllDrives": true,
            "orderBy": "title",
            "maxResults": 1000,
            "q": "'FOLDER_ID' in parents",
            "supportsAllDrives": true,
            "fields": "nextPageToken,items(title,fileExtension,fileSize,labels(starred))",
            "pageToken": pageToken
          });
          if (obj.items.length > 0) fileList = [...fileList, ...obj.items];
          pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
        } while(pageToken);
        console.log(fileList)
      }
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)